# Bash to reorganize CSV file

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, sed, grep

I have a series of CSV files with different data elements in them.  They are structured like this:

datetime, var1, val1, var2, val2, ..., varx, valx

unfortunately, in some instances there is no var1, and in others, var1 will appear later in the line.

**Sample CSV (trimmed to just a few lines, variables)**

```
11/20/2011 3:05:00 AM,HR,115,ST-V,1.2,ST-AVF,-0.1,ST-AVL,0.1,
11/20/2011 3:05:02 AM,HR,119,ST-II,0.1,ST-AVF,-0.1,ST-AVL,0.1,
11/20/2011 3:05:04 AM,HR,122,ST-II,0.1,ST-I,0,ST-V,1.2,ST-AVR,-0.1,
11/20/2011 3:05:06 AM,HR,123,ST-II,0.1,ST-I,0,ST-V,1.2,ST-III,-0.1,
11/20/2011 3:05:08 AM,HR,122,ST-II,0.1,ST-I,0,ST-V,1.2,ST-AVL,0.1,
11/20/2011 3:05:10 AM,ST-V,1.1,ST-III,-0.4,ST-AVR,0,ST-AVL,0.2,
11/20/2011 3:05:12 AM,PVC,0,ST-II,0,ST-I,0,ST-V,1.1,ST-III,-0.4,
11/20/2011 3:05:14 AM,PVC,0,ST-II,0,ST-I,0,APNEA,0,
```

**Ultimately, I'd like to do the following:**

1. Read through the file
2. Copy the datetime stamp for each line
3. Find var1
4. Copy val1
5. If no var1 exists, create var1, insert NaN to val1
6. repeat for all variables
7. save to new csv file

**Desired Output (limited to the two sample variables, will expand to include all variables):**

> ```
> 11/20/2011 3:05:00 AM,HR,115,PVC,NaN,
> 11/20/2011 3:05:02 AM,HR,119,PVC,NaN,
> 11/20/2011 3:05:04 AM,HR,122,PVC,NaN,
> 11/20/2011 3:05:06 AM,HR,123,PVC,NaN,
> 11/20/2011 3:05:08 AM,HR,122,PVC,NaN,
> 11/20/2011 3:05:10 AM,HR,NaN,PVC,NaN,
> 11/20/2011 3:05:12 AM,HR,NaN,PVC,0,
> 11/20/2011 3:05:14 AM,HR,NaN,PVC,0,
> ```

My progress so far has been limited to the following:

```
cut -d',' -f1   # pulls the datetime nicely
grep -n -o 'HR,.*' file.csv | cut -f2 -d','    # works on nearly all variables and pulls the variable from the field following the grep term, but skips all empty lines
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: What should the output look like, exactly?

Comment: thanks - i revised it!

Comment: There are a number of variables with paired values.  If for some reason HR was not detected or measured, it will simply not place a HR variable or value in the line.

Comment: unclear, especially that *var1 will appear later in the line*

Comment: This is physiologic data - if one of the probes we use is not hooked up, there will be no record of it.  If it is hooked up later in the time series, it may appear in field 2-3 and then bump the other parameters down to field 4-5.  If the probe is never attached, it is missing through the whole file.  I'd like to process all of these files to generate a uniform dataset where all values are represented as the measurement or NaN, and such that each column is the same variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very muddy but I **think** this is what youre trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
    numTags = split(tags,tagOrder)
    for (tagNr in tagOrder) {
        tagName = tagOrder[tagNr]
        tagSet[tagName]
    }
}
{
    delete tag2val
    for (fldNr=2; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
        if ($fldNr in tagSet) {
            tag2val[$fldNr] = $(fldNr+1)
        }
    }

    printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
    for (tagNr=1; tagNr<=numTags; tagNr++) {
        tagName = tagOrder[tagNr]
        printf "%s%s%s%s", tagName, OFS, (tagName in tag2val ? tag2val[tagName] : "NaN"), (tagNr<numTags?OFS:ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -v tags='HR,PVC' -f tst.awk file
11/20/2011 3:05:00 AM,HR,115,PVC,NaN
11/20/2011 3:05:02 AM,HR,119,PVC,NaN
11/20/2011 3:05:04 AM,HR,122,PVC,NaN
11/20/2011 3:05:06 AM,HR,123,PVC,NaN
11/20/2011 3:05:08 AM,HR,122,PVC,NaN
11/20/2011 3:05:10 AM,HR,NaN,PVC,NaN
11/20/2011 3:05:12 AM,HR,NaN,PVC,0
11/20/2011 3:05:14 AM,HR,NaN,PVC,0
```

If not then edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Ed Morton - you are amazing.  That worked beautifully.  Sorry if the question was hard to follow, you got the solution right on the first shot.